# SDL Access Violation

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I've created a SDL game project and this window popped up while trying to compile:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in SDL_Game.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The buttons gave the option to `break, continue, ignore`**.**

Code shows no errors whatsoever. Has anyone ran into this sort of problem in the past? I've googled around, but nothing was in line with this that I've found.

**UPDATE:**
Through the debugger, error points to `vShaderID`:

```
GLint Shader::makeVertexShader (char* shaderSource) 
{
    GLint vShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); //<<----- Debugger 
    glShaderSource (vShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**) &shaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShaderID);
    bool compiledCorrectly = compiledStatus(vShaderID);

    if (compiledCorrectly) 
    {
        return vShaderID;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And the second line in the debugger points inside the constructor to `vertexID`:

```
Shader::Shader(const char* vertexFilename, const char* fragmentFilename)
{
    ....
    // Read in the vertex program file
    char* vertexCode = readFile(vertexFilename);
    ....
    GLint vertexID = makeVertexShader(vertexCode); //<<--------Debugger
```

Comment: When you compiled? Looks like a runtime issue, in which case, I'd suggest you run through your debugger.

Comment: @stephelton Thanks for the input. The 1st to line in the debugger points vShaderID and vertexID.

Comment: I had sort of this problem once and my program was just int main() { return 0} It was an access violation at 0x00000000

I restarted my computer and it went away. Maybe give that a try.

Comment: make sure that read file actually returns a valid string. And btw I doubt an exception handler will will make your program continue since this is not a C++ exception, but rather an OS exception (which can be catched in a non-portable way -not recommended- for example SEH on windows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an execute violation at 0x00000000 which means a function call tries to jump to this location.

By the position your debugger points out it looks like glCreateShader is null.

Some of the possible reaons:

- You did not intialize OpenGl correctly/at all? Did you check the return values from the SDL initialization for errors?
- You did initialize an OpenGL version not supporting this function. (glCreateShader requires OpenGL >= 2.0)
- Your platform/driver does not support this feature. This should return an error during initialization as the requested OpenGL is not supported.